# Why is Ruby String.hash inconsistent across machines?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

Came across this today on an app we are deploying across many servers. I was hashing some strings to store in a shared key/value store. The .hash method of String is returning different integers depending on the server. Any ideas why? Note that I am interested in *why*; not possible work arounds.

Example:

```
server1 $ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]

server1 $ irb
irb(main):001:0> "test".hash
=> 4146582576695053125


server2 $ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]

server2 $ irb
"test".hash
=> 3479379392688537032
```

These machines are EC2 instances with the same specs and build.

Comment: We're wondering if you can also show the value of `RUBY_VERSION` from within `irb`.

Comment: For instance:

`ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "1.9.2"`

Comment: `irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.2"` for both

Comment: Any particular reason for expecting them to be identical? And as they're EC2 instances, are they running the same image?

Comment: I believe they are the same image but I did not set them up. My main rationale for them being consistent comes from my java experience with .hashCode. Additionally, there is no mention of them being inconsistent in the String.hash docs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From a Ruby dev in the [Ruby forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/560622):

> It is intended. Ruby 1.9 explicitly use session local random seed to
>   calculate a hash for strings (and some other objects).
>
> This is because the implementation of Object#hash is different between
>   versions (like 1.9.1 and 1.9.2) and implementations (like JRuby,
>   Rubinius, IronRuby, and so on). We want people to write portable code
>   around Object#hash, so we did so.
>
> You should use Digest::SHA256 or some other digest routines when you
>   want some hash value (message digest).

And follow-up from another dev:

> Also, it helps to avoid some denial of service attacks, such as
>   registering hundreds and thousands of users with usernames that have
>   the same hash code.

Comment: Yea, my "work around" was to use Digest but this seemed strange coming from more of a Java background.